# What is the name of the theme used by coderpad

Tags: user-interface, themes

I can't seem to find a defined theme used by Coderpad by default see here https://coderpad.io/sandbox

The closest thing I found was https://vscodethemes.com/e/SarahRidge.vscode-monokai-minimal however some things seem off. Does anybody know what theme they use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colour scheme seems to be a custom one from a Monokai family. The closes I was able to find out of the box is https://github.com/sarcadass/vscode-monokai-alt